# Can I set mobs aflame?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently pondering how effective Flint and Steel would be as a weapon. I'm assuming that it has the same reach distance as a sword/axe, but this would only be useful if I could directly set a zombie on fire. Is it possible to directly ignite such baddies?

On a related note, since wool burns, is it possible to set sheep on fire :3?

Comment: One of my favorite moments in Worms:Armageddon was calling in a French Sheep Strike on my brother's poor worms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Flint_and_Steel):

"Lighting mobs on fire. This method deals damage slower and is less effective than using a sword, and one must click on a block below the mob rather than on the mob itself, rendering it a difficult way to kill."

So, to answer your question, I would suggest just sticking to the sword or bow.

Secondly, because sheep are mobs, you can light sheep on fire. They are no more flammable than any other animal or monster. (Except squid, of course)

Comment: However, Sheep are no more vulnerable to fire than Spiders, Zombies, or Cows.

Comment: That's why I worded it, "Because sheep are mobs." Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You could provide a link to the [page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Flint_and_Steel) from where you copied that quote.

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly set an enemy on fire, but if they walk onto a block that is currently on fire, they will catch fire. Since the mobs will target you, it is pretty easy to light them on fire (bar Skeletons, as they will probably shoot you when you're close enough to light them on fire) as you can just light the block in front of you (even if not flammable, it will burn for a bit) and they should walk into it.

To answer the second part of your question, all mobs can be set on fire.